# c strncasecmp that can handle NULL (character 0)

Tags: c, strcmp, memcmp

I have strings that may contain character 0.  They are stored in a structure like this:

```
typedef struct somestruct_s {
     const unsigned char *string;
     size_t length;
};
```

If I wish to compare 2 of these together I can use memcmp as such:

```
int match = (a->length == b->length) ? !memcmp (a->string, b->string, a->length) : 0;
```

But if I wish to compare 2 of these together without regard to case, my first instinct is to use strncasecmp/_strnicmp -- however, that function stops on null characters.

Is there a common C function already around that can do this.  I don't mind writing my own, but before I do I want to make sure there isn't a standard function that I am unaware of.

Comment: `memicmp` is the case insensitive version

Comment: memicmp, cool.  Thanks!

Comment: roll your own style for non-Microsoft compilers --- http://web.mit.edu/jhawk/mnt/spo/os2/ftp/emx/emx/lib/str/memicmp.c

Comment: It helps if you think of "I have strings that may contain character 0" as "so these are **not** strings".

Comment: A string is a general programming language term not exclusive to C.  The type of strings in C are often referred to as "C strings" or null-terminated strings.  There were strings before the C programming language was ever invented.  In many languages, a string can contain a NULL and they are still called strings.